# Creating gate for process matrix on a quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-computing

I am trying to reproduce Figure 2 from the paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.06056.pdf#page=11&zoom=100,421,138. In this, they have the gate root(X) which in appendix B they have the form in Process Matrix. How can i implement a process matrix in a quantum circuit? P.S I am using pennylane to create the circuit.